# Using npm or Bower in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: npm, bower, package-managers, visual-studio-mac, bower-install

I have a situation in which I need my ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project to be cross-platform.  Unfortunately it appears that I can't use Bower or npm integrated into the IDE (as I can with Visual Studio 2017), so I'm going to need a solution that works for both platforms in order to include the packages I need (https://fullcalendar.io/ being a specific example).  Package managers are mostly foreign to me, so this may be trivially easy but I just need to know how I can approach this in a way that works for both projects simultaneously.